# MySql user created through cPanel gets 'access denied' when trying to log in

Tags: mysql, node.js, cpanel

I have added a user to a database through cPanel called "DB-USERNAME". My cPanel user is "USERNAME". When I am trying to connect to this server, I get a message saying:

`Error: (conn=10219304, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'USERNAME_DB-USERNAME'@'85-76-48-128-nat.******.fi' (using password: YES)`

However, I can login with just the cPanel user just fine. If I try to make any changes, like create a new database or connect to one, I get:

`Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' to database 'test'`

What can I do? I have been stuck with this for a few days now. I can't resolve this with google.

Comment: Presumably you have already asked your hosting service tech support for help. If not, do that first.

Comment: I had not done that, but I did it just now.

Answer (score 2):

Did you join your user name with database in Cpanel, if no then

Please follow below mentioned steps to add a MySQL user to a database:

1. Click MySQL Databases under Databases in cPanel.

2.Under Add User to Database, select the user that you want to add from the User drop-down menu.
3.In the Database drop-down menu, select the database.
4. Click Add.
5. Select the privileges you want to grant the user, or click ALL PRIVILEGES to grant the user all permissions to the database.
6. When ready, click Make Changes.
7. That’s it! You can now see the user assigned to the database in the Current Databases table.

Now check if your issue fixed, if still not fixed then Please check our db connection string.